# AVAssetReader/AVAssetWriter preview of current frame

Tags: ios, avassetwriter, avassetreader, cmsamplebufferref

I'm using `AVAssetReader/AVAssetWriter`  to convert my video on iOS. 
My question is: what's the most efficient way to show preview of current frame with real time conversion.
I was thinking about converting `CMSampleBufferRef` to UIImage, then applying into UIImageView. It there any better way ?

Answer (score 4):

I think [`AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer_Class/index.html) is what you're looking for.

It's a `CALayer` subclass that can display `CMSampleBuffer`s and I imagine it's much faster than a trek through `UIImage` and `UIImageView`.

Here is a simple `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer`-backed `UIView` implementation (in swift):

```
class SampleBufferView: UIView {
    override class func layerClass() -> AnyClass {
        return AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer.self
    }

    func enqueueSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!) {
        let displayLayer = self.layer as! AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer
        displayLayer.enqueueSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    }
}
```